# Why integration constant is real?

Tags: integration, soft-question

OK, we are all taught at school that the undefined integral of a function $f(x)$ is
$$\int f(x)\;\text{d}x = F(x) + k$$
where $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $k \in \mathbb R$.

But, why $k$ *must be* real?

I know the basis of including that $k$ is the fact that the difference between all primitives of a function is a constant, but, couldn't it be complex, and say the following?

$$\int f(x)\;\text{d}x = F(x) + k,\qquad \text{where $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $k \in \mathbb C$}$$

Comment: Maybe it's because we're only dealing with REAL function?

Comment: this is still true for $f : [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ in that case the constant $\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: In principle you're right.  In practice, it's just good pedagogy to take things one step at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the answer is because in high-school you get prepared for "higher" mathematics, so they try not to complicate it too much. First of all, it is obvious that if you only deal with real-valued functions, you will only get real values of $k$. For instance, in my country, the topic of complex numbers is studied apart from everything, and I understood that once I studied complex analysis in the university. You cannot just go to a high-school class and talk about complex functions, because some of these are defined in special ways (logarithms, powers, trigonometric functions, etc.). That is why we study complex **numbers** and not complex **analysis** (from my point of view, of course).

Also, one more example of a similar fact: the first time we learn to solve quadratic equations (kids are around 14 y.o. when they learn that), whenever a solution of such equation is a complex number, they just tell students that *there is no solution* (some years later they learn there is actually a solution, which is not real). I am not saying this statement is right or wrong, I am just stating how they teach us in my country. The same with integrals, some years later you will be taught that $k$ can also be complex in some cases.

Comment: As we live in the same country (and we have studied / are studying in the same city, as I can see in your public profile), I suppose that I will have to cope with complex integration constants later, so I really appreciate your point of view ;)

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not the case that $C$ must be real. Whenever you have a function, you always need to specify where it maps. Is it $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$? $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$? $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^n}$? Since we, in calculus, very often deal with functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, this is sometimes left off and assumed that the reader will know, however we do talk about function in other function spaces.

If $f:A\to B$, then the constant of integration must be an element of $B$. This is easily seen, as $F(0)=C$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it can be.

It's just that in Calc I, II, III you strictly deal with functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so if you want these functions to be closed indefinite integration, you need the constant to be $\in \mathbb{R}$.